# IE11 window.open doesnt load page in existing tab

Tags: tabs, internet-explorer-11, window.open

I have a page which opens a second tab in IE11 and then in the second tab i want to be able to click a button and have that cause the first tab to load a different page. I am including a simple example which works correctly in Chrome, but not in IE11.

In the code below i explicitly set the window.name of the first tab to PascalPage, and even though i reference this name in the window.open call in page2.html it loads the Google page in the page2.html tab instead of the page1.html tab

**Page 1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page1</title>

    <script>
        this.window.name="PascalPage";
        function doStuff() {
            window.open("page2.html", "_blank");
        }
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:doStuff();" value="button">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page2</title>

    <script>
        function doStuff() {
            window.open("http://www.google.com", "PascalPage");
        }
    </script>
<head>
<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:doStuff();" value="button">Button</button>
</body>
```

In my Internet Settings options the selected option is to allow IE to decide how to handle tabs.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

```
        function loadUrlInTab(targetwindowname, url) {
            //open the url in the targetwindowname or new tab if the target window isnt already open
            winref = window.open('', targetwindowname);
            winref.location.href = url;
            winref.focus();
        }
```

The window.open() call returns a reference to the window with 'targetwindowname' and then its a simple case of setting the location for that window.

PS. I found that in Chrome the instruction to focus() works, but in IE11 it doesn't. But that is a minor issue overall.